# Question removed with no explanation or notification

Tags: support, specific-question, deleted-questions

Yesterday the question formerly accessible via https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10769113/reverse-engineering-a-protocol-buffer-protobuf-data-stream was removed by someone.

This is the link to Google cached version: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:_IorRJjT230J:stackoverflow.com/questions/10769113/reverse-engineering-a-protocol-buffer-protobuf-data-stream+

Why was my question removed?

Who removed it?

Why wasn't I notified?

If it was removed because it was considered off topic. Is there another stack exchange it would fit better?

Comment: The question seems to be of the type "list of" or "request for recommendation", which are generally seen as not a good fit for the site. Why you weren't notified I don't know...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your question is this:

> Are there any tools or libraries (preferably in Java) that help in
>   reverse engineering a protobuf stream? Is it possible to generate a
>   .proto file from such a stream?
>
> I can observe both sides of the communication (client and server).

This is not a good fit for our Q&A format, as it's asking for a recommendation instead of a solid technically correct answer that receives votes based on the merits of the answer alone and not the value or popularity of the suggestion.

If, however you *found* such a tool and encountered some problem using it, your question would be welcome.

I'm not sure why the moderator that handled the flag deleted the question upon closing (which is what took you by surprise). It could be that there's no way to edit that question to fall within our guidelines without completely changing the scope, at which point it should probably just be a new question altogether.

Perhaps Bill just saw this likely unavoidable scenario, and given the fact that you have 450+ reputation points he just assumed you knew.

Comment: I'd still like to know *who* deleted it instead of closing it first and thereby notifying me about that there was a problem.

Comment: I mentioned the moderator in my reply. Specifically, it was @BilltheLizard.

Answer (score -2):

You need to check out [What kind of questions can I ask here? - StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions) because it seems that your question wasn't relevant to this site and Constructive.

There is clearly written in FAQ: You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.

Comment: I think the answer which is not constructive/not relevant to the site, it should be closed first, then the user gets the notification and he had a chance for voluntarily removing the question. I think your answer is inconsistent. Unfortunately, i dont have enough reputation to downvote your answer.....